# Nuxeo : Upload using presigned URL

Tags: amazon-s3, nuxeo

I want to generate a presigned URL for an S3 bucket, and upload files using the url, not through nuxeo server or the direct upload option.

The [documentation](https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/amazon-cloudfront-distribution/), says, that I need to set the `CloudFrontBinaryManager` as the binary manager to be used. Despite, setting the configuration in `nuxeo.conf`, I am not able to upload directly to the bucket. I still see the request made to `/upload`, which routes the upload through the nuxeo server to the s3 bucket.

The downloads happen through the presigned url, but the upload doesn't. How can I make the upload work?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://answers.nuxeo.com/general/q/e57c88455afd4e5896450656547ab381/How-to-upload-to-S3-bucket-using. If you cross-post then please mention it in a comment so that people don't waste their time answering in two places.

Comment: 0 times 0 = 0 => 0 people wasted 0 time